# How to animate ng-repeat loops without using ng-animate?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I'm working on a project where I cannot use ng-animate in certain situations due to the way the angular apps are bootstrapped. Therefore, I've been trying to figure out a way to animate the ng-repeat loops using regular Jquery/CSS animations.

Is there a way to bind to ng-repeat events (enter,leave,move...) without using ng-animate?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested. The idea here was not to do things in a wrong way. But to think on alternatives due to the situation I am.

Here's a simple solution to make animations using pure JQuery/CSS transitions while still using ng-repeat to manipulate the DOM insertions/removals:

`code here >>` http://plnkr.co/edit/K1qH2WNJw1ZbjcmZ1qDU

Have fun!